# Displaying up to date input signals with tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, gpio

python 2.7

I'm using a raspberry pi to monitor some digital input signals as an hobby project. I want to have a large display that shows the accumulated values and updates them with global variables that will keep track of the input signals. I'm going to be using push buttons on a breadboard for now so I tried to use a holding variable to keep the counters from incrementing every cycle. I am very new to Python as I'm sure this is obvious so please keep it simple if possible. I am calling one input `PE_MATTRESSES`, another `PE_COMBINED`, and the other `RESET`, I want to display a third value that subtracts `PE_MATTRESSES` from `PE_COMBINED`. Of course `RESET` will zero everything..

My pseudo code though process is:

- establish I/O and global variables
- create GUI
- while 1
  -- look at I/O
  -- update global variables
  -- update labels to display them
  -- loop

My code is as follows:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


PE_MATTRESS = GPIO.input(17)
PE_MATTRESS_LATCH = 0
PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR = 0
PE_COMBINED = GPIO.input(21)
PE_COMBINED_LATCH = 0
PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR = 0
BOXSPRING_ACCUMULATOR = 0
BOXSPRING_ACCUMULATOR = PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR - PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR 
RESET = GPIO.input(22)



class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        # create a custom font
        self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=117)


        # create widgets 

        label1 = tk.Label(root, text="MATTRESSES: %s" % PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR , font=self.customFont)
        label1.pack()

        spacer1 = tk.Label(root, text="", font=self.customFont)
        spacer1.pack()

        Quit = tk.Button(root, text="QUIT", command=quit)
        Increment = tk.Button(root, text="Test", command=Inc)
        Quit.pack()
        Increment.pack()


        label2 = tk.Label(root, text="BOXSPRINGS: %s" % BOXSPRING_ACCUMULATOR, font=self.customFont)
        label2.pack()

        spacer2 = tk.Label(root, text="", font=self.customFont)
        spacer2.pack()


        label3 = tk.Label(root, text="      COMBINED: %s" % PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR, font=self.customFont)
        label3.pack()



        root.geometry('1800x1000+0+0')
        root.after(10,Inputs)

        root.mainloop()

    def Inc():

        PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR = PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR + 1
    label1.setText("MATTRESSES: %s" % PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR)
    label2.setText("BOXSPRINGS: %s" % BOXSPRING_ACCUMULATOR)
    label3.setText("      COMBINED: %s" % PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR)

        root.update_idletasks()


    def Inputs():

        if PE_MATTRESS == True and PE_MATTRESS_LATCH == False:
            PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR = PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR + 1
            PE_MATTRESS_LATCH = True


        elif PE_MATTRESS == False and PE_MATTRESS_LATCH == True:
            PE_MATTRESS_LATCH = False

        elif PE_COMBINED == True and PE_COMBINED_LATCH == False:
            PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR = PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR + 1
            PE_COMBINED_LATCH = True

        elif PE_COMBINED == False and PE_COMBINED_LATCH == True:
            PE_COMBINED_LATCH = False

        elif RESET == True:
            PE_COMBINED_ACCUMULATOR = 0
            PE_MATTRESS_ACCUMULATOR = 0

app=App()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code includes a `while 1` loop, but your actual code does not. Also, `Inc()` is never called. I suggest you add the following lines to the end of `Inputs()`:

```
self.Inc()
self.root.after(10, self.Inputs)
```

You'll also have to make `root` an instance variable, i.e. include `self.root = root` in `__init__()` for this to work.